# Where to find further explanation for Binance API endpoints?

Tags: api, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to understand the dynamics of how Binance API works and it's been a while now since I started navigating through the [Official Binance API Docs](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#change-log). The problem is that the documentation doesn't explain neither the parameters of the API end points nor the server response.

For Example, the documentation for [placing margin orders](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#margin-account-new-order-trade) only shows an example of the server response message without any explanation of what the response fields actually mean and what are the possible values for each field and how they are calculated (**such as `status` and `timeInForce` fields**).

Does anyone know where can I find a detailed explanation for these API calls?

Comment: Looking at your example link `timeInForce` field values are GTC,IOC,FOK which is pretty self explanatory don't you think? That being said if you thinking of coding in python you might want to look at the ccxt library which simplifies api access to multiple exchanges. https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/tree/master/doc & https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Also, your question is not specific enough. You need to provide some code so we can see what you have done so far and we will be able to help. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

You can find official Binance REST API documentation [here](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md)

You can use a python [binance-client](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) packege for almost every task.

A better package named [ccxt](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) can also be used for binance api interaction

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).